# global scope enum and namespace conflict

Tags: c++, com, enums, atl, midl

I have an ATL COM service and in the .IDL file, I've declared an enum like so:

In Gourmet.idl

```
typedef enum Food
{
    Chocolate = 0,
    Doughnut,
    HotDog
} Food;
```

A header file is automatically generated, creating Gourmet_i.h.

In another .CPP file (let's just call it Decadence.cpp) of the same ATL COM project, I #include Gourmet_i.h. I've implemented a class in this .CPP and it's under the namespace 'Chocolate'.

For example in Decadence.cpp:

```
#include "Gourmet_i.h"

namespace Chocolate {

// Constructor
void Decadence::Decadence() {}

// ... and so on

} // namespace Chocolate
```

When compiled I get the following error about Gourmet_i.h:

```
error C2365: 'Chocolate': redefinition; previous definition was 'namespace'
```

I see this occurs because the enum for the IDL is defined in the global namespace, but is it possible to contain this definition -- so it doesn't pollute the global namespace -- and I wouldn't have this conflict?

Comment: What is the point of that `typedef`? This isn't C. In C++, tag lookup is performed automatically without having to specify `enum` or `struct`.

Answer (score 4):

Short of renaming the namespace or enum member about the only solution for this is to wrap the contents of the generated header file in a namespace. This is not without pitfalls and depending on how the contents of your MIDL file it may eventually cause a few headaches. The cleanest way that I can see would be to create a proxy header file that declares the namespace then includes the MIDL generated header file.

`Gourmet.h`

```
namespace MIDLStuff
{
    #include "Gourmet_i.h"
}
```

Comment: this seems to be the cleanest way to do it. worked for me.

on a side note, I'm going to start staying away from declaring enums in COM interfaces.

Comment: @ykay: whether you declare an enum in IDL or not should not be driven by this problem. If you define a method that uses the enum, you need the enum in the interface. Some people choose to name the enum members `fdChocolate`, `fdDoughnut`, etc. That might work for you as an alternative. The fact that enum members are unscoped is a quirk of C (and inherited by C++), not IDL's fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++11 you can use Scoped Enumeration by including `class`:

```
typedef enum class Food
{
    Chocolate = 0,
    Doughnut,
    HotDog
} Food;
```

Now you need to write `Food::Chocolate` when using the value.